# Why Mojolicious render_maybe implicitly changes stash?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I have changed default Mojolicious application in next way:

1. Add route `/test` into `MyApp.pm`

```
   # Normal route to controller
   $r->get('/')->to('example#welcome');
+  $r->get('/test')->to('example#test');
}
```

2. Add action `test` and template into `MyApp::Controller::Example.pm`

```
+
+sub test {
+  my $self =  shift;
+
+  $self->render_maybe( 'not_existent1', foo => 1 );
+  $self->render_maybe( 'not_existent2', bar => 2 );
+  $self->render;
+}
+
+1;
+
+__DATA__
+@@ example/test.html.ep
+$foo $bar
```

3. Then run:

```
./script/my_app get /test
```

The output is `1--2`. This is not expected because I render template without any arguments.

I'm inclined to believe that this behavior is the bug.
If not tell me please how to prevent original `stash` while trying to render other templates?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that stash keys for [`render_maybe`](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/blob/master/lib/Mojolicious/Controller.pm#L188) should be localized in same way as they are localized for [`render_to_string`](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/blob/master/lib/Mojolicious/Controller.pm#L190) [here](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/blob/master/lib/Mojolicious/Renderer.pm#L83)

Comment: Are you rubber-ducking and coming up with the answers to most of your questions really fast or are you building your own little FAQ with weird Mojo questions? In any case, it's interesting. :)

Comment: @simbabque I spent whole day yesterday. Also ask about this at official IRC. And did not get answer yet: is this expected behavior  or not. This this answer actually is not. Because suggested localization breaks some tests. Posting here I hope to find people whose also faced this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In similar situaion I use [Mojolicious::Renderer::template_path()](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Renderer#template_path):

```
sub test {
  my $self =  shift;

  $self->render_maybe( 'not_existent1', foo => 1 ) if $self->app->renderer->template_path({ template => "not_existent1, format => 'html', handler => 'ep'});
  $self->render_maybe( 'not_existent2', bar => 2 ) if $self->app->renderer->template_path({ template => "not_existent2, format => 'html', handler => 'ep'});
  $self->render;
}
1;
```

OR better create helper:

```
  $app->helper(template_exists => sub { 
       shift->app->renderer->template_path({ template => shift, 
                                             format => 'html',
                                             handler => 'ep'})
  });
```

and then:

```
sub test {
  my $self =  shift;/Mojolicious::Renderer#template_path

  return $self->render( 'not_existent1', foo => 1 ) if $self->template_exists('not_existeunt1');  
  return $self->render( 'not_existent2', bar => 2 ) if $self->template_exists('not_existeunt2');
  $self->render;
}
```